# Simulating hierarchical / multi-level data for regression analysis in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, simulation, multilevel-analysis

I want to simulate a dataset whereby I have a continuous variable that represents a response to treatment (normally distributed). The dataset should also include sex (50:50) and age (normally distributed) when starting treatment.

I want to create the dataset such that:

1. If I perform a linear regression on sex or age across all individuals, I would obtain beta estimates similar to effect estimates of age and sex previously published. I know how to simulate such a dataset using the `simglm` library in R.
2. If I split individuals based on sex and then subsequently split again based on above or below median age, I would obtain mean estimates of response as previously published within those groups. I know how to simulate differences in response in each group (e.g. males and under median age) using random variables drawn from different distributions using functions like `rnorm()` in R where the differences in means across groups reflect previously published average response estimates.

The issue is that I don't know how to essentially do the two tasks above "simultaneously" to achieve both objectives. I realise that the dataset I wish to create is described as "hierarchical" / "multilevel" but am not quite sure how to get to a place where I can implement a simulated model that does both 1 and 2 above. Does anyone have any ideas of how this could be done in R? I was thinking that the `simglm` package might be able to do this but I've struggled to follow the vignette re random effects that may or may not help here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell us more about your data structure. Are the people (or whatever your units of analysis are) at level 1 or level 2? In other words do you have people clustered within higher level units (families, classrooms, etc) or measures clustered within people.

Comment: Hi Jeremy. I think the individuals will be level 1 in that they can be grouped into the mutually exclusive groups related to sex and lower/upper age groups that form to level 2?

Comment: This doesn't sound like hierarchical data. Typically this is where individuals are nested within groups, and these groups are sampled from a population (e.g. you have analyze  100 individuals who are in 50 families - your families are considered a random sample of possible families). You have two sexes, this is not a random sample of all sexes, it's all (2) of them.

Comment: OK thanks. So do you know a way to solve the problem I describe?

Comment: I would use the mvrnorm() function in the MASS package. This will generate data that are sampled from a population with specificed means and covariances.